# Using webview as an dependency

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I want to know if it would be possible to have WebView as a dependency (adding in build.gradle) or like a independent library (I couldn't find how to get the original library independently from MavenCentral)?

Because I have a serious problem regarding [Google automatic update of WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77799181/webview-stops-working-after-google-automatic-update) for some months,  and unfortunately I couldn't solve it by now.

So I really need to decide when to update WebView, and get rid of this automatic update.

It updates automatically at least once per week, and it causes the whole crash on my app (even on my sticky foreground service which should be running 24-7 and be in foreground).

Since it should be on large amount of users' devices, it is not possible to login to google play store and disable Automatic Update for all of them.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/prerelease.md#trichrome-beta

[image: stable channel updates]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if it would be possible to have webview as a dependency (adding in build.gradle) or like a independent library (I couldn't find how to get the original library independently from MavenCentral)?

If by webview you mean `WebView`, then no. You do not control that.

However, you could look into [using Mozilla's `GeckoView`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/) or see if somebody has a Chromium-based `WebView` replacement for which you control the updates.